# Append image to <td> via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm struggling with an issue appending an image to an `<td>`-element . Unfortunately I'm not able to show you an complete jsfiddle (values-calculation is rather complex), but I hope some code snippets are enough.

Table-Structure:

```
var table = createElement('table');
var header = table.createTHead();
var row = header.insertRow(0);
var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
cell0.innerHTML = "Indikator"
var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = "In dieser Region"
var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
cell2.innerHTML = "Alle Regionen: Höchster Werte"
var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
cell3.innerHTML = "Alle Regionen: Niedrigster Werte"
var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
cell4.innerHTML = "Alle Regionen: Durchschnitt"
var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
cell5.innerHTML = "Bewertung";
tbody = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));
```

Then I'm using a for-loop, where the rest of the table is created:

```
for (var key in values) {
    //...
    //method to calculate some values
    ...
    //append values to tbody
    $(table).find(tbody).append("<tr>");
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+(indicatorValue)+"</td>");
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+(regionValue)+"</td>");
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+(bestValues)+"</td>");
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+(worstValues)+"</td>");
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+(average)+"</td>");
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+ createIndicator(picIdentifier));
}
```

All the methods are working properly, but I have some issues with the last part, the **createIndicator(picIdentifier)**, which is used to refer to the image source.

```
function createIndicator(state) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    if (picIdentifier == 'green') {
        img.src = "img/green_circle.png";
    } else {
        img.src = 'img/red_circle.png';
    }
    return img;
}
```

Coming to my problem: The images are not created, but it's only stated `[object HTMLImageElement]` for each cell, where the image should be located. You can check it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLj6R.jpg

I've tried some workarounds, and also come to an result, where the images will be created by using `$(table).find(tbody).append(createIndicator(picIdentifier));` but with this I do not create the images in table-cells. Check it here, how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKC5L.jpg

Would be awesome to get some tips from you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this will work, don't go for function

```
  var img = "<img src='img/green_circle.png' />";
  if(picIdentifier != 'green')
  {
    img = "<img src='img/red_circle.png' />";
  }
  $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+ img +"</td>");
```

you can not return the element, it will always return object, so either you append it in function or use my code.

Comment: Is it possible to arrange its size?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using either Firefox or Chrome, right click on the image, and select Inspect Element, to check for any potential DOM errors. Remember that it has to be wrapped in `<td></td>`'s.

Comment: No DOM-errors at all. By calling the **createIndicator**-method, it also returns the right value: http://imgur.com/YrgjrKe

Comment: I meant for the part where the images don't show up as table cells at  http://imgur.com/7POq3wn

Comment: I got it working. Anyway: Thank you for your time and your effort :)